# Get multiple columns from database?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jdbc

I've using the following the code to get a list of columns from a database table.

```
val result =
    sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(Map(
      "driver" -> "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
      "url" -> jdbcSqlConn,
      "dbtable" -> s"...."
    )).load()
    .select("column1") // Now I need to select("col1", "col2", "col3")
    .as[Int]
```

Now I need to get multiple columns from the database table and I want the result to be strongly typed (DataSet?). How should the code be written?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:-

```
val colNames = Seq("column1","col1","col2",....."coln")

val result = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(Map(
  "driver" -> "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
  "url" -> jdbcSqlConn,
  "dbtable" -> s"...."
)).load().select(colNames.head, colNames.tail: _*)

val newResult = result.withColumn("column1New", result.column1.cast(IntegerType))
.drop("column1").withColumnRenamed("column1New", "column1")
```